# Why is this outer wall warping?

Tags: pla, troubleshooting, creality-cr-10

I am printing a battery compartment cover on my CR-X Pro. Upon removing the cover I see that some of the outer walls are warping. I have tried printing this same piece with and without bed heat, cooling fans, and both via an SD card and OctoPrint. I don't know where else to try and eliminate the problem. The corner of the extended part in the images below did have an adhesion problem but the issue occurs regardless.

Separately if you have any knowledge on why the printer leaves little burs on the print that would be appriciated, I've tried messing with both retraction and z-hopping on that front.

I am currently using Cura for any recommendations of slicing settings.

[image: Warped wall close up]
[image: Warped wall close up other side]
[image: Overall battery cover]

Comment: Tra calibrating E steps and then check first layer height

Comment: Hi! For me also this print looks like the printer is non-calibrated, regarding the amount of extrusion and maybe the temperature. Some places look like over-extruded, and the middle infill has holes. Adhesion problem may be caused by [unclean bed or other issues](/q/15327/), which may be more important.